# Trying to read data file into a 2D Array and print to screen

Tags: java, arrays, dimensional

I'm trying to read data from a file and load into a two dimensional array and then print it to the screen.
but i keep receiving error code

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)
    at test.main(test.java:14)
```

Here is my code below. Any advice would be great. I Feel like im missing something stupid and just need another pair of helpful eyes here. thanks

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class test{ 

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{ 
        double [][] P= new double [5][3];

        BufferedReader Infile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("P08RATE.DAT"));
        StringTokenizer Tokens;
        while (Infile.ready()){ 
            Tokens = new StringTokenizer(Infile.readLine());
            for (int k=0; k<P.length; k++)
                for (int j=0; j<P[k].length; j++)  
                    P[k][j] = Double.parseDouble(Tokens.nextToken());
        }
        Show(P);
    }

    /*-------------- Method: Show() ---------------*/
    private static void Show(double C[][]){ 
        int i, j;
        for (i=0; i < C.length; i++){ 
            for (j=0; j < C[i].length; j++)  
                System.out.print("  " + C[i][j]);
            System.out.println('\n');  
        }
    } //PrintArray

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what you're trying to do without seeing the input file. But if it's strictly something like

```
double double double
double double double
double double double
double double double
double double double
```

You should have the line

```
Tokens = new StringTokenizer(Infile.readLine());
```

Inside of your first for loop.

Comment: Yes! that was the problem. Thank you so much man. I was going absolutely nuts over it. Can't vote up yet. not enough rep.